# How to pivot rows to data with T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the following data:

```
code  desc       amt   month
----- ---------- ----- ------
aa    item aa    12    4/2019
aa    item aa    7     5/2019
bb    item bb    5     4/2019
bb    item bb    35    5/2019
bc    widget bc  109   3/2019
bc    widget bc  100   4/2019
df    widget df  29    5/2019
```

I want to pivot this data so that it looks like this:

```
code  desc       3/2019   4/2019   5/2019
----- ---------- -------- -------- --------
aa    item aa         0       12        7
bb    item bb         0        5       35
bc    widget bc     109      100        0
df    widget df       0        0       29
```

All of the pivot examples I see include aggregation functions, but, I don't want to aggregate, I just need to combine/transpose the data. How can I do this?

Comment: you can use MIN or MAX to pseudo-aggregate if you have a unique row for each month

Comment: @Vasya I think they will not be unique in this case since that column is the 'amount'.

Comment: No, they are unique records for each "item" and "month". For example, there is only one "4/2019" row for code "aa".

Comment: Unless you know in advance exactly which months you're after, you can look at this tip for some ideas about constructing dynamic pivot queries: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/

Comment: So, I poked around these suggestions and realized I also needed to output the columns, and I came up with this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1eb25221711ffc369d22c0ba0391a0d1 Not the most elegant solution, but, it works! Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want dynamic columns ... then you'll need a little dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From YourTable
 Pivot (sum(amt) For [month] in (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(month) 
                                               From YourTable A  
                                               Order By 1 
                                               For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
--Print @SQL
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The Dynamic SQL Looks like this**

```
Select *
 From  YourTable
 Pivot (sum(amt) For [month] in ([3/2019],[4/2019],[5/2019]) ) p
```

Comment: They do need to be dynamic (a new column will be added every month). This is a good starting point for what I need...

Comment: This worked perfectly for my needs, as I was able to join it to another view in a Stored Procedure to generate the resultset I needed for my report. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any way to use ISNULL for the dynamic columns to set them to zero if they are null?

Comment: @EricBelair Certainly.  One method is to construct a second list of column names which would produce ..., [3/2019] = isnull([3/2019],0) ...   Or my preferred technique is create a sub-query which generates an intersection of data combinations.   Give me a few and I create send you a dbfiddle

Comment: @EricBelair Take peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=75157cd11415f65bc1ecec0f5cef51fc   Notice the src subquery with a UNION ALL

Comment: @EricBelair Second option using IsNull()   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5d857289af9c7c2f627f4076a562deb5

Comment: Thanks! I look forward to trying this out!

Answer (score 0):

There is a pivot function you can directly use in T-sql, try this 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017